# Is there a Flex IDE/development env that works on Ubuntu 64bit?

Tags: linux, apache-flex, ide

Is there a good Flex IDE/development env that works on Ubuntu?
Where can this be found?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/fb4linux/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Flex on Ubuntu: The Complete How To Guide](http://orensol.com/2009/03/24/flex-on-ubuntu-the-complete-how-to-guide/) describes all the available options, the most prominent one is :

> [Flex Builder Linux Alpha](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/flexbuilder_linux/) is an
>   Adobe free product, which is a Flex
>   build environment as a plugin for
>   Eclipse. Don’t worry about the Alpha
>   part, it seems like a very stable
>   product, and besides eating up some
>   memory, I had no problems with it. It
>   is actually an exact replica of the
>   Flex Builder for Windows, without the
>   features of Design View, some wizards
>   and the profiler.

Comment: This alpha is about to expire.  Please vote for the FB on Linux feature request on Adobe's site:

http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-19053

Answer (score 1):

[Flex on Ubuntu](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=1G1TSEA_ENIN311&=&q=flex+builder+ubuntu&btnG=Google+Search)

Loads of resources out there.

Comment: Of course theres loads of resources there, thats why I am asking which is the best...

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Flex Builder Linux for more than 2 years, and it works great. 
An installation guide (with patch for Eclipse 3.5 & 3.4) is available here:

http://ducquoc.wordpress.com/2010/10/26/flexbuilder-eclipse-plugin/

Another option is FB4linux : 
code.google.com/p/fb4linux/

and FDT:
fdt.powerflasher.com/

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but Adobe seem to be developing a [linux version of flex builder](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/flexbuilder_linux/).

Comment: They seem to *have been* developing a linux version. The last release was an alpha, released more than a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

[IntelliJ IDEA 9](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/index.html) also now supports Flex development.

Comment: But not in the new community edition.  Only in the "Ultimate" edition.